# R Highcharter heatmap x-axis categories

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I need to show all months in the x-axis of a heatmap. You can see from the minimal example there is missing Sales data for Feb-19 but I would like the heatmap to include it anyway as an empty column.

I tried including a dummy variable in the data with Sales value of NA, which includes the missing month but then the tooltips don't work.

```
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

# 1. Create data with missing month

heatmap_data <- data.table(Fruit = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'),
                                 Month = c('2019-01-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01'),
                                 Sales = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

highcharter::hchart(heatmap_data,
    type = "heatmap",
    highcharter::hcaes(x = Month, y = Fruit, value = Sales))


# 2. Attempt with dummy entry included

heatmap_data <- data.table(Fruit = c('apple', NA, 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'),
                                 Month = c('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01'),
                                 Sales = c(2, NA, 4, 6, 8))

highcharter::hchart(heatmap_data,
    type = "heatmap",
    highcharter::hcaes(x = Month, y = Fruit, value = Sales)) %>%

    highcharter::hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 4)
```

The second attempt displays all the desired months on the x-axis but then I lose the tooltips. Is there a better way of dealing with these missing months?

Update 2019-08-21
Using @Ben's example with issue in shinymaterial shiny app:

```
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinymaterial)

heatmap_data <- data.table(
  Fruit = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'),
  Month = c('2019-01-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01'),
  Sales = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

heatmap_data$Month <- datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date(heatmap_data$Month, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) 

ui <- material_page(
    title = "Heatmap Example",
    highchartOutput("heatmap")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$heatmap <- renderHighchart({
        highchart() %>%
            hc_chart(
                type = 'heatmap'
            ) %>%
            hc_add_series(
                data = heatmap_data,
                type = 'heatmap',
                hcaes(x = Month, y = Fruit, value = Sales),
                colsize = 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 30,
                tooltip = list(
                    pointFormat = '{point.x:%b, %Y}, {point.y}: {point.value}'
                ),
                showInLegend = FALSE,
                borderWidth = 4
            ) %>%
            hc_xAxis(
                type = 'datetime'
            ) %>%
            hc_yAxis(
                categories = heatmap_data$Fruit
            )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second attempt with NA for 2019-02-01, perhaps add the tooltip formatter explicitly:

```
hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 4,
           formatter = JS('function (tooltip)
             {return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);}
           '), shared = TRUE)
```

**Edit**: This solution above threw a javascript error (see comments).

*Alternative 1*: If the dataset included the month as numeric (and not a date), then the heatmap would plot correctly with missing data for February. Note month indexed at zero for month.abb.

```
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)

heatmap_data <- data.table(Fruit = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'),
                           Month = c(0, 2, 3, 4),
                           Sales = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

hchart(heatmap_data,
       type = "heatmap",
       hcaes(x = Month, y = Fruit, value = Sales)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = month.abb)
```

*Alternative 2*: If the Month variable is left as a date, then it could be converted with datetime_to_timestamp in milliseconds. The xAxis should then be of type 'datetime'. Colsize is also necessary to match time in milliseconds from timestamp for better approximation of width. I hope this might be helpful and closer to what you had in mind.

**Edit**: This solution includes shiny implementation and does not give any js errors for me:

```
library(highcharter)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)

heatmap_data <- data.table(Fruit = c('apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'),
                           Month = c('2019-01-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01'),
                           Sales = c(2, 4, 6, 8))

heatmap_data$Month <- datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date(heatmap_data$Month, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) 

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Heatmap Example"),
    mainPanel(highchartOutput("heatmap"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$heatmap <- renderHighchart({
        highchart() %>%
            hc_chart(
                type = 'heatmap'
            ) %>%
            hc_add_series(
                data = heatmap_data,
                type = 'heatmap',
                hcaes(x = Month, y = Fruit, value = Sales),
                colsize = 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 30,
                tooltip = list(
                    pointFormat = '{point.x:%b, %Y}, {point.y}: {point.value}'
                ),
                showInLegend = FALSE,
                borderWidth = 4
            ) %>%
            hc_xAxis(
                type = 'datetime'
            ) %>%
            hc_yAxis(
                categories = heatmap_data$Fruit
            )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This helped when running locally on my PC but when I deploy to shinyapps.io I receive the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined" leading to crashes. Having NA's in the series seems to be a problem for highcharter. So I am still looking for a solution @Ben

Comment: thanks for the update, sorry to hear - i'd like to review this again later today further...

Comment: @Greg unfortunately no luck so far - while the tooltip did work when deployed in a shiny app, I reproduced the same js error (not just with the deployed app but also locally when I opened in browser and checked the console). The error comes up with the NAs by itself without any changes to the tooltip. I hope others might post a better solution. I'll keeping trying...

Comment: Thanks for trying Ben, yes I saw the js errors locally too but they didn't crash the app; only an issue once deployed. I will keep trying too as I'm sure there must be a way of dealing with missing data points in a series.

Comment: If you used numeric month (1, 2, 3) instead of date (2019-01-01...), it seems to work. The heatmap will leave empty space for second month (Feb). As an alternative, you can convert your heatmap_data$Month to timestamp: heatmap_data$dateTime <- datetime_to_timestamp(as.Date(heatmap_data$Month, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) and add hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") as another pipe in your render method, and that partially gets somewhere (still need to figure out mouseover highlighting and convert text in tooltip). So far cannot see how to get around a Fruit with NA name and not get a js error in highcharter

Comment: @Greg See edits for alternative, hope this might be helpful.

Comment: I couldn't get the datetime_to_timestamp solution to work. I thought the numeric xaxis had fixed it but still getting js errors

Comment: @Greg What js errors are you getting? Same? I don't get any js errors with either solution. I went ahead and edited the answer so it contains all of the code including shiny implementation for the second solution.

Comment: Hi @Ben, apologies for the delay, I have tried to get this to work on a few occasions. Your example does work in the toy example I gave, but I can't scale it up to fix my real issue. However, that may be due to the package I'm using- please see update where I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: c.className.indexOf`

Comment: Hmmm...looks like all that was added was shinymaterial --- do you still get the error if you remove all the server code and just leave the ui? i'm not able to reproduce the same error. it might be worthwhile to try to create the minimum example that gives the error (and maybe post a separate question)? i wish i could be of more help.